# Please burn some [jrxml] weed under my oak

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[jrxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jrxml) is the file format of [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports). If it is jrxml, you can be sure it is a Jasper report.

The  [all-time top answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876298/alex-k) of [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) is making a great effort to edit and remove or replace [jrxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jrxml) with [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports). [jrxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jrxml) is an unnecessary tag, that doesn't provide additional information. I did an effort to remove the last 12...

So let's just **burn this weed away**, once and for all...

Comment: You do seem to have it with oak trees, hmm?

Comment: @Magisch, yes I really love the shade they give, it is nice to have a calm place on SO.....

Comment: This is a metaphor instead of a pun this time, right?

Comment: @BSMP as usual, just some color to an otherwise boring post...., and weed has always some interesting meanings...

Comment: This title is like something from Arqade.

Comment: It's fully burned down now; to keep it from coming back should it be made a synonym of jasper-reports?

Comment: It almost sounds like a mission from gta3 sa :D

Comment: **Tie a yellow ribbon on the ol' oak tree..."* (sings) But seriously, TBH, the [jrxml] read to me like a replacement for a common expletive starting with an F in Find.

Comment: "A simple yellow ribbon's what I need to set me free"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I totally agree with Petter. It is an absolutely useless tag. In case of using this tag the author of question talking about the *JasperReports*  framework